# XML to MD-Array

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I'm trying to convert a XML feed to Array

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<products>
    <auction>
        <uniqueid>360116 05</uniqueid>
        <title>puma</title>
        <category>men / puma</category>
        <description></description>
        <price>111.00</price>
        <currency>eur</currency>
        <brand>puma</brand>
        <photos>
            <url>http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=1</url>
            <url>http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=2</url>
            <url>http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=3</url>
            <url>http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=4</url>
            <url>http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=5</url>
            <url>http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=6</url>
        </photos>
        <stocks>
                <stock>
                    <amount>1</amount>
                    <size>44</size>
                </stock>
                <stock>
                    <amount>1</amount>
                    <size>43</size>
                </stock>
                <stock>
                    <amount>1</amount>
                    <size>42</size>
                </stock>
        </stocks>
    </auction>
</products>
```

I use this function to convert the XML to Array but is not working well as I expect.
For example there are 6 URLs in  and when it converts to array it's only one URL.  aare not working as well

```
protected function xml2array($xml) {
    $temp = [];

    foreach ($xml as $k => $element) {
        $tag = $element->getName();
        $e = get_object_vars($element);

        if (!empty($e))
            $temp[$tag] = $element instanceof SimpleXMLElement ? $this->xml2array($element) : $e;
        else
            $temp[$tag] = trim($element);
    }

    return $temp;
}
```

After conversion

```
Array
(
    [auction] => Array
        (
            [uniqueid] => 360116 05
            [title] => puma
            [category] => men / puma
            [description] => 
            [price] => 111.00
            [currency] => eur
            [brand] => puma
            [photos] => Array
                (
                    [url] => http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=6
                )

            [stocks] => Array
                (
                    [stock] => Array
                        (
                            [amount] => 1
                            [size] => 42
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

How can I add all URLs and Stocks in Array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to parse an XML to arrays is to [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) the [`SimpleXMLElement`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) object returned by [`simplexml_load_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) then [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) the JSON, passing `TRUE` as the second argument:

```
$xml = <<< END
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<products>
    <!-- your XML here -->
</products>
END;

$array = json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($xml)), TRUE);
```

Take a look at the output here: https://3v4l.org/nKKDn.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to

```
if (!empty($e)) {
    $temp[$tag] = $element instanceof SimpleXMLElement ? $this->xml2array($element) : $e;
} elseif (array_key_exist($tag, $temp)) {
    if (!is_array($temp[$tag])) {
        $temp[$tag] = array($temp[$tag]);
    }
    $temp[$tag][] = trim($element);
} else {
    $temp[$tag] = trim($element);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @FieryCat